# How do I pass literal variable templates to jq from within Make?

Tags: bash, makefile, interpolation, jq

I'm trying to use jq within a Makefile to generate a json file. Here is a sample Makefile

```
foo.json:
    jq -n --arg x "bar" '{"foo": "$$x"}' > foo.json
    @cat foo.json
    @rm foo.json
```

When I run this with GNU Make v4.3 and jq v1.6 I get the following

```sh
make
jq -n --arg x "bar" '{"foo": "$x"}' > foo.json
{
  "foo": "$x"
}
```

Notice that `$x` shows up literally and doesn't get interpolated by jq. How do I achieve the following...

```sh
make
jq -n --arg x "bar" '{"foo": "$x"}' > foo.json
{
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

Comment: Writing a makefile recipe correctly is very easy.  First, ensure the command works at the shell prompt.  Then, copy that same command into your makefile recipe _and_ replace each instance of `$` in the command with `$$`.  Done.  If you're having problems with the first part, then it's not a make issue :)

Comment: `"$x"` != `$x`; customcommander's answer is on-point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply don't need to wrap your variable in quotes:

```
jq -n --arg x "bar" '{foo: $x}'
```

Or use string interpolation:

```
jq -n --arg x "bar" '{foo: "\($x)"}'
```

Comment: The concern here is preventing `make` from munging the string before it gets to the shell (much less to jq). Have you tested that this works correctly in a makefile?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I understood that part. OP has done it with double escaping the var: `$$x`.

Comment: Indeed, but it behooves an answer to a question asking about a specific case to be tested in that case, and still applicable thereto.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @customcommander for the tip. The answer was not quoting the dollar signs or the var at all. Updated Makefile confirmed working...

```sh
$ cat Makefile 
foo.json:
    jq -n --arg x $X '{"foo": $$x}' > foo.json
    @cat foo.json
    @rm foo.json

$ X=123 make
jq -n --arg x 123 '{"foo": $x}' > foo.json
{
  "foo": "123"
}
$ X=456 make
jq -n --arg x 456 '{"foo": $x}' > foo.json
{
  "foo": "456"
}
```

Comment: Please note that you can simplify your Makefile by referring to your target with `$@`  e.g. `foo.json:; jq -n --arg x $X '{"foo": $$x}' > $@`

Comment: *Do* keep quoting the variable outside of your jq code. Changing from `--arg x "$X"` to `--arg x $X` creates bugs (when it's parsed by bash). By contrast, in `'{"foo": $x}'` only the outer quotes are parsed by bash (and inner ones are passed through to jq unmodified); *there* (and only there!) is removing the quotes both necessary and unambiguously correct.

Comment: It's safer to use `--arg x "$$X"` in the Makefile in case `$X` contains double quotes.

Comment: thanks for the tips, everyone working as intended now. Is it customary to update my answer to reflect the comments now?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up avoiding jq `--arg` entirely and went with a *simpler* approach.

Example Makefile:

```
# the arg to pass to jq
SOME_VAR?=my-var

foo.json:
    jq -n  '{"foo": "'"$(SOME_VAR)"'"}' > foo.json
    @cat foo.json
    @rm foo.json
```

Example usage:

```sh
$ make foo.json
jq -n  '{"foo": "'"my-var"'"}' > foo.json
{
  "foo": "my-var"
}
```

Quoted variables work too:

```sh
$ SOME_VAR="hi" make foo.json
jq -n  '{"foo": "'"hi"'"}' > foo.json
{
  "foo": "hi"
}
```